# Move an aligned item in a GridLayout

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt5.3

I've got a 2x2 Gridlayout. All items are Aligned left and each column spans 50% of the space.

Now I'd like to move one of the 4 items of the GridLayout 20 pixel more to the right. How do I this?

```
import QtQuick 2.2 
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Gridlayout {
   rows: 2
   flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
   TextEdit {
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
      text: "test 1"
   }
   Image {
      // This one is supposed to be aligned left + 20 pixels
      source: "cool-pic.jpg"
   }
   TextEdit {
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
      text: "test 3"
   }
   TextEdit {
      text: "test 4"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution. It works and maybe it will be useful for you. You can change width as you want

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

GridLayout {
   rows: 2
   flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
   TextEdit {
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
      text: "test 1"
   }

   Row{
       Rectangle{width: 20;height:parent.height; color:"transparent"}
   Image {
      // This one is supposed to be aligned left + 20 pixels
      source: "sub/tst.jpg"
   }
   }
   TextEdit {
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
      text: "test 3"
   }
   TextEdit {
      text: "test 4"
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for convenience sake I want with 4x TextEdit but I actually need to move an Image. I updated my original question.

Comment: @Hedge I totally updated my answer. See my edit please.

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.